# Mac Terminal command to move cursor on screen?

Tags: macos, terminal, cursor

Is there a way to move the cursor around the screen (`XXXxXXX` location?) using terminal?

Comment: Do you *really* only want to move the cursor, or do you want to execute clicks??

Comment: Both would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at this: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2008051406323031

Depending on what you are trying to do you could try Automator to script the behavior.

```
/Applications/Utilities/Automator
```

I don't believe there is any inbuilt commands that will enable you to do what you want easily.

Comment: Hey so I put it in the bin folder, but when I call it I get the 

-bash: /usr/local/bin/click: Bad CPU type in executable

error. What's my problem?

Comment: Did you download the prebuilt binary? Link: http://www.macosxhints.com/dlfiles/click_binary.zip I've just tested this on a mac running os x 10.6 and it works

Comment: PowerPC is your problem. Maybe time to upgrade :)

Comment: @Matthew Eley I'm working on it. So why won't it run on a PowerPC? What can I do to make it run? Where else can I find a script to do this?

Comment: You can't make it run unless you have an intel chip in your machine. I wouldn't spend much more time on it. If you're desperate to get it working I would look into automator. Regards

Answer (score 1):

11 years after :)
To move the cursor from the Terminal, you can use swift: [CGWarpMouseCursorPosition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456387-cgwarpmousecursorposition)

For instance the following script puts the cursor at position 123x456

```
import Cocoa
CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(CGPoint(x:123,y:456))
```

To have information on screen size, one can use NSScreen.main!.frame

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling to get `cliclick` to move my mouse, while it was working for moving and clicking. I tried @koko256's answer and while it worked I found Swift way too painful to try and even use variables as arguments for the move command. Instead, I managed to easily put this together in Python, achieving the anti-afk functionality I was after:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Requires: pip3 install pynput
import time
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

mouse = Controller()

# Save original coordinates
OG = mouse.position

# Move to new place and click (tiny delay needed)
mouse.position = (720, 12) 
time.sleep(0.01)
mouse.press(Button.left)
mouse.release(Button.left)

# Return to original position
time.sleep(0.01)
mouse.position = (OG)
```